# how to set (org.kohsuke.stapler.) Stapler root in a directory not /?

Tags: java, servlets

this is probably a stupid question, but I'd like to set Stapler to a directory not /

for example, from this site

http://stapler.kohsuke.org/getting-started.html

since I set the Stapler root to be

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Stapler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Stapler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this means that the URL

```
http://myserver:myport/
```

is mapped to the Stapler servlet. This is ok.

Now, I'd like to make it answer to

```
http://myserver:myport/somedir
```

obviously, just changing the configuration below is not enough

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Stapler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Stapler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/somedir/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

how can I change Stapler in this case?

TIA

Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's a Stapler bug. Please see the open issue at https://github.com/stapler/stapler/issues/24